# How to make Alt-F4 close every program/game, even those that ignore it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, gaming

I think you know the problem, if you want to close a program, especially a game with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, nothing happens.

Sure, I know every programmer can choose what will happen, if the user presses <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, but can you solve this problem with a litte other program or a registry tweak?

Answer (score 1):

[SuperF4](https://github.com/stefansundin/superf4) seems to do what you want, though it uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> instead. I haven't used it myself, so no guarantees on quality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it would help with the programs troubling you, but [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is a free, well-known program for re-mapping keys, and it uses a script that includes commands for minimizing and closing windows, etc.

So, for example, if you wanted to be able to close windows using the shortcut, Ctrl+X, then you would include this command in your AutoHotKey script:

^x::WinClose, A

If you read the help pages or search for specific keywords in them, you should be able to find clues about how to add a different shortcut for that. I never had to read the full help pages; only ever searched for specific tips, found them, and taught myself how to use it through the months with a couple of minutes here and there, even though it felt confusing or overwhelming the very first time.

Hope this helps.